# Which is standard usage in British English?

Tags: phrases, british-english, quotes

Which is standard usage in British English?

1. He said, 'Bite me.'
2. He said, 'Bite me'.

Comment: Neither, 'bite me' is an American phrase.

Answer (score 4):

Since the quoted text forms a complete sentence, the period should be included with it, inside the quotation marks (Oxford Manual of Style, section 5.13.2).

Really, this has little to do with standard, British English usage, and I wouldn't sweat it. If this level of detail matters to you, get the relevant style guide. You will need one for trickier punctuation problems.